# Adding conditions to an if statement

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

I'm designing a Competition schedule but I'm stuck with the conditions.

I have made 5 conditions where the competition should meet these.

I have to do in a greedy algorithm way.

I've come up with this so far:

```
while len(gamesgreedy) != len(games):
    v1 = CompetitionSchedule.violation_team_round_multiple(
        self, gamesreedy, start_index)
    v2 = CompetitionSchedule.violation_bye_per_team(
        self, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    v3 = CompetitionSchedule.violation_double_city(
        self, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    v4 = CompetitionSchedule.violations_double_match(self, gamesgreedy,)
    v5 = CompetitionSchedule.violations_home_away(
        self, gamesgreedy, start_index)

    for x in gamestup:
        gamesgreedy.append(x) if sum(v1, v2, v3, v3, v4, v5) <
```

I have a pool of all possible matches and I want to add one for one the match with the fewest violations and so on until I get the full schedule.

The violations are integers. So at the beginning `gamesgreedy` is an empty list and then add match `1` and check if this brings the fewest violations compared to all the other matches.

After this, I'll have to repeat this step where the functions check now the `gamesgreedy` with match `1` and match `2` in it, and so on.

Comment: Your objective isn't really clear . . .

Comment: I tried to make It clearer now, thanks.

Comment: The final line with `if sum(v1...` likely won't execute. It should flow as `if sum(v1...` then `gamesgreedy.append(x)` in a new code block. On one line: `if sum(v1,v2,v3,v3,v4,v5) < ?: gamesgreedy.append(x)`

Comment: Yes I know  I looked at it for hours and then decided to put in online. I want to compare it to all possible options and then add the one with the fewest violations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move evalution to a function.

```py
def calculate_violations(self_, gamesgreedy, start_index):
    v1 = CompetitionSchedule.violation_team_round_multiple(
        self_, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    v2 = CompetitionSchedule.violation_bye_per_team(
        self_, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    v3 = CompetitionSchedule.violation_double_city(
        self_, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    v4 = CompetitionSchedule.violations_double_match(
        self_, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    v5 = CompetitionSchedule.violations_home_away(
        self_, gamesgreedy, start_index)
    return sum([v1, v2, v3, v4, v5])
```

Until you process all matches map each remaining match to the number of violations, select the match with minimum violations, and use it in the next step.

```py
gamesgreedy = []
while len(gamesgreedy) < len(games):
    match_violations = {
        match: calculate_violations(self, gamesgreedy + [match], start_index)
        for match in games if match not in gamesgreedy}
    best_match = min(match_violations, key=lambda m: match_violations[m])
    gamesgreedy.append(best_match)
```

The `gamesgreedy` variable then contains matches in optimal order.

*Note that this is just the best guess considering the unclear question's objective.*

Comment: @Frank123 You may possibly "accept" the answer to inform future readers that it matches your expectations.